# How to get "name" or "id" while redirecting the page

Tags: php

I coded a web page that displays the "name","phone" & "e-mail" of customers in "table row" from mysql using PDO.

What I want to do is when the row(example: `Alex 04325262 alex@mail.uk`) is clicked the details(`"name","phone", "e-mail", "address","last message"`) of `"Alex"` (that are saved before in mysql) need to be shown in another page.

I am struggling in passing the `"name"` (or other info) of customer to the new page. If I can access the data in the new page I can re-search from mysql e.g:

```
("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name='Alex'")
```

and display it. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Put them in the SESSION array.

Comment: you can pass it with `href`

Comment: Better choice SESSION array :D

Comment: use Session in this senairo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even its easily can be done with `href` but as Jay Blanchard mentioned `SESSION Array` so you can do it like this

By assuming that you can adjust the following code according to your requirement

```
$_SESSION['name'] = "Alex";
$_SESSION['phone'] = "04325262";
$_SESSION['email'] = "alex@mail.uk";
```

Note: Don't forget to add `<?php session_start();?>` top of your file

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that whenever you want to store `session` data you run `session_start()` prior to using or assigning to the `session` array.

To store the name into your session assuming you have the name stored in a variable e.g. `$name` do this:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
```

The value of `$name` will now persist in the PHP session.

To access that value in your other pages ensure that you call `session_start()`, then you can simply access the value like so:

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Example output:

> Alex

Note that you only need to run `session_start()` once per page.

For more info please refer to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Comment: Your user table should ideally have an ID column as its primary key to uniquely identify each user which you would use in your session. You may need to amend your table schema.

Comment: The only real way to do this is via MySQL, otherwise you can't guarantee that the same ID will get attached to each user. If you need help open another question and people will be able to give you a run through.